# jQuery on click and cancel event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

With bootstrap, we have about 10 buttons. Using jquery, a modal will appear with another 2 buttons, cancel and confirm.

Now, when I click confirm, modal will close and the state of the button will change. E.g Blue change to Green.
When I click cancel, modal will close.

The problem is this: When I click the first button and cancel, then click the second button and confirm, both buttons will change to green.

It goes the same for 4 buttons or 5 buttons.

Does it have anything to do with this

```
var $this = $(this);
```

What code should I put in the cancel button to clear $this if that's the problem?

Comment: post your code, nobody can help you with so little information.

Comment: The question does not make any sense without the code

Comment: well, first thing you should do is show your code..!

Comment: Sounds like a scope issue. But as all others: Show some code :)

Comment: I'm sorry, i tried to add this link but could not. http://jsfiddle.net/vFDSZ/20/

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are using class name of button to change the color.You should use the id of button instead of class name of that button.

Comment: sorry, the version of my fiddle is not changing colors. It changes the word to click.

Click Button1, then cancel
Button 2, then cancel

Comment: lastly click button 3 and confirm. Which buttons show "Clicked"?